# conditional subtract in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to subtract 2 cells in 2 rows if the value of other cells are the same:

| fruit | company | date | Driver |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| apple | A | 12/12/2023 | xx |
| apple | A | 12/13/2023 | yy |
| apple | B | 12/15/2023 | zz |
| banana | B | 12/15/2023 | ww |

the first 2 rows are for the same fruit by the same company. so I want to know how long was the difference of delivery ( in this case 1 day: Dec13-Dec12)

can you give me any solution? it should be sth like sumifs but in subtraction

I have can filter the if part but not able to do the subtract:
countifs(A:A,"apple",B:B,"A") gives the repeated records

Comment: =IF(AND(A2=A3,B2=B3),C3 -C2,"")  You can put that in E2 and copy down.  If your date field has time as well you can format as time to see the difference easier.

Answer (score 1):

It is not fully clear on your explanation whether more than 2 rows are possible with same fruit type and company, but with given data sample this would give desired result for those 4 rows:

```
=MAXIFS(C2:C5,A2:A5,"apple",B2:B5,"A")-MINIFS(C2:C5,A2:A5,"apple",B2:B5,"A")
```

Result:

[image]